# Calling a Method several times with several Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, gpio

I want a LED to flash, while some work is beeing done on my Raspberry. I am using a Thread for the LED in my Python script.

The initial code:

```
import RPi.GPIO
import time
import threading

pinLED = 10
pinButton = 12

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(pinLED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pinButton, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.output(pinLED, 0)
```

Method for the Thread:

```
working = False
def flash():
    status = 0
    while working:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if status == 0:
            GPIO.output(pinLED, 1)
            status = 1
        else:
            GPIO.output(pinLED, 0)
            status = 0|
    GPIO.output(pinLED, 0)
```

Logic:

```
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.02) #found out that 0.02 is a good value to get every tiny button push and save resources

        if GPIO.input(pinButton) == 1:
            t = threading.Thread(target=flash)
            working = True
            t.start()

            time.sleep(5) #work would be here
            working = False
            t.join()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I start the script and press the button the first time, everything is working and the led is flashing. But when i press the button a second time, without restarting the script, the led isn't flashing. I printed some debug messages and found out, that t.start() is called, but for some reason it's doing nothing, also no Exception is thrown. Shouln't the LED start flashing every time I press the button again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no *logic* fault and i confirm it works, but used the following changes:

1. Starting the `main_thread` from inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`.
   I suggest to move also all `GPIO` calls inside this `block`.

Avoid placing code that is executed on startup outside of `if __name__ == '__main__':`

> *From the docs:*
>    Safe importing of main module
>    One should protect the “entry point” of the program by using if __name__ == '__main__':

2. Added `join()` after `working = False`, this guaranteed the thread has terminated befor starting it again.

   ```
   working = False  
   t.join()
   ```

---

I would suggest to change the `def flash()`, to the following:
Using `threading.Event()` instead of a `global Instance` and passing it together with the `pinLED`.
This generalizes the `def flash(...)` and allow its use with different `pinLED`, even parallel.
Define `status` as `threading.local()` threadsafe, so instance’s values will be different for separate threads.
For instance:

```
def flash(pinLED, flashing):
    status = threading.local()
    status.LED = False
    while flashing.is_set():
        status.LED = not status.LED
        GPIO.output(pinLED, int(status.LED))
        time.sleep(0.5)

    GPIO.output(pinLED, 0)
```

Changes to the `main_thread`:

```
def main_thread():
    flashing = threading.Event()
    flashing.clear()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.02)  
            if GPIO.input(pinButton) == 1:
                t = threading.Thread(target=flash, args=(pinLED, flashing,))
                flashing.set()
                t.start()

                time.sleep(2)  # work would be here

                flashing.clear()
                t.join()
    ...
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Comment: Yes, the if statement should be inside the while loop, I corrected it. I didn't want the thread to be active all the time, because maybe once a day the button will be pushed and i don't want to waste the resources for the thread all the other time.

Comment: It's working, thank you very much! Hope I ticked your answer correctly as working, I'm quite new to stackoverflow. Just comment if I did it wrong.